# Beginning Python Emacs & Terminal Setup

Tags: python

I'm new to python coding and I'm trying to create a simple program in emacs.

```
print "Hello World"

def foo():
    return "FOO"

def Bar():
    return "BAR"
```

In the terminal I have figured out how to run the inicial "HELLO WORLD" but not the methods.

```
$python Test.py #test.py is my file name
Hello World
```

now, how do I run my methods? Foo and Bar

Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with Emacs, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line in the same directory.

```
$ python
>> from Test import *
>> foo()
"FOO"
>> Bar()
"BAR"
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside your Python script, invoke them:

```
print "Hello World"

def foo():
    return "FOO"

def Bar():
    return "BAR"

print foo();
print Bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

One common practice is to create a `main()` function, which allows you to define other helper functions anywhere else in the file. This can be done by calling `main()` in a conditional with `if __name__ == '__main__'` (the `__name__` and `__main__` are special values for the Python script).

```
def main():
    foo()
    Bar()

def foo():
    return "FOO"

def Bar():
    return "BAR"

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```